# Android recyclerview item xml layout

Tags: android-layout

Want the xml layout for the recyclerview item shown in the image. Any help??[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you really want to understand, how you can do this, like in your shown picture, you should start with tutorials like:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

and

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

(first results after google search with: "recyclerview tutorial")